To what extent can quantum indeterminancy be held to contribute to macroscopic randomness?
Related to this question Can we have reliable deterministic reasoning processes if our universe is fundamentally non-deterministic? arise the questions about the interface between the microscopic and macroscopic worlds. Certainly, quantum effects can be isolated and amplified to have a profound impact on real world phenomena. For instance, quantum uncertainty can be harvested to produce randomness for cryptographic systems. But what of other cases? Does the presumption of the existence of free-will, for instance, claim that some chance in the world (as held distinct from random as per Chance versus Randomness (SEP)) is not of quantum origins? Are there other sources of chance? In other words, what sorts of philosophical schools of thought hold that quantum indeterminancy only partially contributes to macroscopic chance?

Not every mutation is due to quantum randomness. In living system also thermodynamic random noise - in particular during the copy of chromosomes - is responsible for mutations which may produce a random effect on the macroscopic scale. That's a fact from biology, one does not need a philosophical argument to explain it.

Are you asking whether some philosophers defend indeterminism that is not of (ultimately) quantum origin? "Chance" and "randomness" are too ambiguous in common use to make that plain. I suppose miracles and other divine interventions would qualify. Free will as a sui generis causality breaker was popular in the 19th century, but more recent defenders (Popper, Compton, Eccles, Penrose, Kane) typically link it to amplified quantum effects.

@Conifold Thank you. I believe I am asking after sources of macroscopic indeterminism  not of quantum origin, and perhaps then as a corollary if macroscopic sources are ultimately all derived from quantum effects. Besides quantum effects and macroscopic sources, then it seem the only options left, given one's metaphysical presuppositions, are free will and supernatural forces. Thanks for the additional players in the persons of Compton and Cane.

Mind you, there is no such thing as "the microscopic and macroscopic worlds". There is no difference between the "quantum world" and the "real world". It's just one world seen at different scales. So the question does not make much sense.

I can see photons with my naked eye alright. Leptons and leopards are different things but they share a common world.

In a way, photons are the only thing you will ever see.

When you're at it, you may as well fix the OP wording about two worlds and this neat "interface" between them, leptons on one side, leopards on the other. It's not the right way to think about it.

@Olivier5 I decline graciously. Thanks. ; )

Give it some thought (he insists). There is no interface, the way I see it, just different scales of representation.

In science, no other source for indeterminacy than quantum Indeterminacy is known. As per the SEP article linked in the question, "chance" however is not always considered linked to indeterminacy, so there's a lot of fineprint to consider.
Outside science, some other speculative sources of indeterminism are

Divine intervention
Libertarian free will (which has many different forms, many of which do not mention quantum effects)
Strong emergence could cause indeterminacy (but does not have to)
... more are possible


Thanks! Emergence was a term I hadn't connected with indetermninacy

Whilst there is quantum indeterminancy, there is also classical indeterminancy. The latter arises from the fact we cannot measure absolutely precisely. This means there is such a thing as classical chaos.
It should also be admitted that classical determinism arises arises as an emergent phenomena from quantum indeterminancy.
It's impossible to state with any degree of accuracy to what degree macroscopic indeterminancy is due to quantum indeterminancy as there is vast range of systems to consider.

One discussion is mentioned in Carnap's book. The following sentences are cited from Carnap's book Philosophical Foundations of Physics, in Chapter 22 - Determinism and Free Will.

'In recent years, a number of writers have suggested that
indeterminate quantum jumps, which... Now it is quite true that under
certain conditions a microcause, such as quantum jump, can lead to an
observable macroeffect. In an atom bomb,...
'Think for a moment of a human being at the instant of making a
decision. If, at this point, there is the type of indeterminacy
exhibited by a quantum jump, then the decision made at that point
would be equally random. Such randomness is of no help in
strengthening the meaning of the term "free choice". A choice like
this would not be a choice at all, but would be a chance, haphazard
decision, as though a decision between two possible courses of action
were made by flipping a penny...'
'The indeterminacy in quantum mechanics has no observable effect on
what happens to a stone when each man throws it, because the stone is
an enormous complex consisting of billions of particles... For this
reason I regard it as a misconception to suppose that indeterminacy on
the subatomic level has any bearing on the question of free
decision...'

You may want to read the whole chapter first, and it is indeed quite interesting.
I hope this source will be useful for you ^^
Reference:
Carnap, R., & Gardner, M. (1966). Philosophical Foundations of Physics. An Introduction to the Philosophy of Science.

Indeed it is, if no other regards I have a profound interest in philosophy of science and logical positivism. In fact, it seems to suggest that macrophenomena are inherently resistant by constitution to quantum effects. Thanks a heap. It's also a kick in the pants (since I have, but not read past the first two chapters. ; )

There is no other source of randomness besides quantum indeterminacy (indeterminism is not the correct term here). All observable macro scale inaccuracies are just combined effects of a large number of quantum scale events.
The behaviour of solid objects is quasi-deterministic, as they behave like their constituent particles do on the average. However this average is never exactly as predicted.
The behaviour of individual particles in chaotic systems cannot be predicted at all. Therefore chaotic systems can be described only statistically.
